Jdt.ls forces package names to match directories
I use Neovim + jdtls, and I have recently found out that Java compiler doesn't actually care if files packages and their location do not match.
That was a relief because I really disliked it when even a root class is 5 directories far from the project root, and with growth of project's classes hierarchy the problem increases to the point when even the directories names do not fit in my nvim-tree window. So I thought that it would be reasonable if the src/java directory would correspond to the project root package (e.g. com.examle.app), and with directories only for the subpackages. The problem is that jdt.ls doesn't allow that, saying The declared package "com.example.app" doesn't correspond to the expected package "" and not being able to resolve any of my class names.
I looked at nvim-lspconfig docs, but didn't find if there's a way to fix that. Maven and Gradle don't have any problems with that so I thought that there might be a way to make Jdt.ls to do what I want.

You probably already expected a rant that "java should always use package = directory". However really, modular java (module.info) and general security considerations on visibitly of packages outside jars, make it problematic. Maybe consider NetBeans / IntelliJ / VSstudio as IDE.

Eclipse JDT uses its own compiler (ecj) rather than javac. i think ecj insists on the directory corresponding to the package
